# Tab navigation with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navigation step by step from bootstrap nav. I would like that the user could only access the next tab by clicking the button at the bottom of each tab.

I've tried adding the class `disabled` and some JS but despite the change of style your content remains accessible. If any of you have done something similar or know another easier method (plug-in or other), please do not hesitate to respond.

[My code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0x5STfdcLmo1Zj06RGWR?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the "wizard" plugins for this functionallity. I've tried the https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard

You can set it up, in a way, that clicking on tabs will have no effect:

```
onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very good tip! Maybe this will help me, really. I'm working with asp.net and need to do validations for each transition, the biggest challenge may be that due to the postback. Thanks!

Comment: My use case was that i've all the steps where an ajax response from posting a form in the given step. In the wizard configuration, I have something like this:
`if (!$(currentTabId + ' form').valid()) //check normal validation
    return false;
$(currentTabId + ' form').submit();
`

Comment: I adapted the solution to my problem. :)